# Creating summaries helps us understand a new language?

Tags: learning-methods, reading, writing

At school we were "forced" to summarize the text, but does it help in learning a new language?

Comment: This question is better suited to [languagelearning.se], but the short answer is *yes*. It makes you read the passage until you really understand it, and then also makes you express that understanding in the new language. It exercises two relevant skills. That's why your teachers and administrators, all professional educators, put it in the curriculum. It works, if you put the time in.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Regular members can't migrate to LL.SE. Only diamond mods can.  You can either mod-flag the Q or simply re-ask it (under your own acct) on LL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is useful in multiple ways:

1. Writing (or Speaking, if the task is oral) -it teaches you to express your thoughts in the target language.
2. Reading - it makes you read more carefully to comprehend more thoroughly.
3. Vocabulary - it is another exposure to the language. You will have to struggle to bring words into your mind while writing or speaking, which is a good thing by itself. We retain in our memory the words that we use better.